# XMLHTTP readyState 3 Not Updating in Webkit

Tags: javascript, ajax, webkit, xmlhttprequest

This question has been asked twice on these forums, but the answer provided is not working for me.

The issue is that I have  JSP page which is returning and flushing small amounts of output.

I am using the following code to read the output:

```
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { 
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
} else { 
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
}

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {               
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 3) {
        alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
}

xmlhttp.open("POST", "download.jsp", true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', "XMLHttpRequest");
xmlhttp.send($('#submitDownloadForm').serialize());
```

On Firefox this works fine, and I am given 3 alerts during the duration of the process.

However, on Webkit based browsers such as Chrome and Safari, I am given the first alert, but not the other 2 until the process has completed.

Other answers have said that changing the `Content-Type:text/plain` or `Content-Type:application/octet-stream`, but if I do this, the `readyState` jumps straight to 4 as if the process has completed instantly.

I cannot find any solutions for this.

Any help greatly appreciated, thanks in advance everyone.

Comment: Not sure if it works, but have you tried `xhr.onprogress` event?

Comment: @Passerby Thanks for your comment, the same problem persists though. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the following code to the JSP file just before where it produces the output, and this has resolved the issue on Webkit-based browsers:

```
response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
```

I'm now getting the updates every time output is flushed.

Comment: But in your question you said that this will causes `readyState` to jump straight to 4...

Comment: Indeed, it was where I put the set content header that did it for me, beforehand I was putting it in the Ajax request.